# Не могу понять, куда вставить номер?

Tags: python, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
api_hash = "xxxx"
api_id = xxx
client = TelegramClient("anon", api_id, api_hash)
async def main():
    me = await client.get_me()
    print(me.stringify())
    username = me.username
    print(username)
    

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

отвечает мне мол "Please enter your phone (or bot token): "

Comment: Вы использовали оператор `-`, а не `=`, разве так задумывалось? (Смотрите переменную `api_id`)

Comment: ой, нет, там в коде =, а здесь просто опечатался когда id удалял

Comment: просто учусь по документации, но там про номер ничего не написано

Comment: Судя по всему `api_id` должно быть пяти или семи значным числом, а не строкой.

Comment: Все ровно просит номер. Не помогло

Comment: Что это за название сессии, `"Anon"`? Вы хотите после работы программы не сохранять сессию?

Comment: так было указанно в документации.